# Learning Curve on two classifiers

Tags: regression, boosting, binary-data, curve-fitting

I am using a logistic regression classifier and Gridsearch to optimize negative log loss.
After generating its learning curve to test for overfitting/underfitting, my model seems to return this learning curve. Note that my y-axis is log loss, and my x-axis is my iterations.

Is this a sign of good fit? I wasn't sure as my training score curve looked a bit odd since its started to rise again at the 5000th iteration.

[image]

I also have the same data set trained on a XGBoost classifier, and after using Gridsearch to optimize hyper parameters for negative log loss, I was achieving this for my learning curve. This is most definitely overfitting correct? What is the best way I can utilize GridSearch to both optimize negative log loss, yet also prevent overfitting/underfitting.

[image]

EDIT:
The code I used to plot the Learning Curve.

```
#learning curve       
    train_sizes, train_scores, val_scores = learning_curve(
    model, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='neg_log_loss', train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10)
    )

    # Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the training and validation scores
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    val_scores_mean = np.mean(val_scores, axis=1)
    val_scores_std = np.std(val_scores, axis=1)

    # Plot the learning curve
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.title("Learning Curve")
    plt.xlabel("Training Examples")
    plt.ylabel("Log Loss")
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, val_scores_mean - val_scores_std,
                     val_scores_mean + val_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")

    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training Score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, val_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Validation Score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What does the horizontal axis with training examples represent? Is your model gradually updated or refitted each time after adding new samples or increasing the sample size? Could the model have made a small 'mistake' at 5200 due to some random outlier, an error that is reduced in the steps following it?

Comment: What does the shaded region represent?

Comment: For the first question, I used a gridsearchCV to optimize hyperparamters and then fitted the final model. I added the code I used to plot the chart, hopefully this solves your second question.